# In DNN Platform can I add a user to a social group programmatically?

Tags: dotnetnuke

In DNN Platform can I add a user to a social group programmatically? If so how would I do that (i.e. what would the code look like/class functions)

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you mean is create a role under Social Groups, here's some code I made to generate some test roles under Social Group.

```
public void CreateTestRoles(int number)
        {
            RoleInfo rInfo;
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {
                rInfo = new RoleInfo();
                rInfo.RoleGroupID = 2;
                rInfo.RoleName = "client test" + i;
                rInfo.Description = "A social Group";
                rInfo.SecurityMode = SecurityMode.SocialGroup;
                rInfo.Status = RoleStatus.Approved;
                RoleController.Instance.AddRole(rInfo);
            }
        }
```